# malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin with vue dynamic contents outside the box

Tags: jquery, css, vue.js, mcustomscrollbar

I am trying to use this [jquery plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) with vue, I read its bad to include jquery with vue but I can't help it since client specifically demand to use this plugin...

So i did this

```
import jquery from "@/assets/js/jquery.js";
import malihu from "@/assets/js/mCustomScrollbar.js";

export default {
    name: 'messages',
    methods:{
        bindScrollbar(){

    $("#content").mCustomScrollbar({
          theme:"kb",
        });

        }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.bindScrollbar();
    },
}
```

This works normally if the contents are static. But if i load the contents dynamically using v-for, the contents are created outside the scrollable box... Btw, i'm using webpack and single file components. Need help

Solution I tried so far:

re-attach the generated content to the container upon change using watch like this but it does not work also:

```
watch: {
    'contentValue': function(val,oldVal){
        console.log($("#content")); //<-- log shows that dynamic contents are generated outside the mCSB_container...
        var el = $(".contents").detach();
        $(".mCSB_container").append(el); 


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it, I should have put the bind, on updated(), instead of mounted() since i am loading the data dynamically... no need to watch for it...

```
updated(){
  this.bindScrollbar();
},
```

Comment: Don't work for me, have you some other solution or more information about this problem?